# Unhandled Rejection error in stripe paymnet method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i use stripe as payment. here in my code its generate clientSecret and request comes in my stripe account but it's incompltete and shown **The customer has not entered their payment method**.
and when i click on pay now button error is come that

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
```

and in console...

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_1HWKxuFi3enyg1Glqirj0Wto/confirm 400
undefine  //that means paymentIntent is not definr
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined 

at async handleSubmit
```

here is my code..

```
useEffect(() => {
       const getClientSecret = async () => {
                   const response = await axios({
    
                    method: 'post',
                    url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
                })
                console.log('response is >>>>>>>>>>>', response)
            
                setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
            }
            getClientSecret()
        }, [basket])
    
        console.log('the secrate is >>>>>>>>', clientSecret)
    
    
        const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            setProcessing(true)
            const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
                }
    
            }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
                console.log(paymentIntent)
                db
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(user?.uid)
                    .collection('orders')
                    .doc(paymentIntent.uid)
                    .set({
                        basket: basket,
                        amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                        created: paymentIntent.created
                    })
    
                //payment  
                setSucceeded(true)
                setError(null)
                setProcessing(false)
    
                dispatch({
                    type: 'EMTY_BASKET'
                })
                history.replace('/orders')
            })
        }
```

whyt is error?
and why i am getting it??

Answer (score 1):

my answer is solved...

Just make sure you are putting the same currency.

For example: if you have mentioned India as your country then put "inr" else "usd"